# Query causing consistent load on SQL Server long after query is complete

Tags: sql-server, database-performance

After restarting SQL Server, so I am on a blank slate at low CPU, I run this query:

```
UPDATE [UserRoleMappings]
  SET LastSeenLocation = [Location], LastSeenLatLng = [LatLng]
FROM (
  SELECT  urm.ID, ps.Location, ps.LatLng
  FROM    UserRoleMappings urm INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  TriggerUserID,
                    MAX(CreatedAt) MaxDate
            FROM    [PageStatistics] ps
            GROUP BY TriggerUserID
        ) MaxDates ON urm.UserID = MaxDates.TriggerUserID INNER JOIN
        [PageStatistics] ps ON MaxDates.TriggerUserID = urm.UserID AND MaxDates.MaxDate = ps.CreatedAt
) i
WHERE i.ID = UserRoleMappings.ID
```

[image]

9239 records were affected, and the query ran fine within 00:00:00 seconds. However, continually after the query has long ran the CPU load is now floating between 29-45% consistent load indicated by this screenshot. This load never seemed to decrease until I restart SQL Server:

Comment: it may or may not have anything to do with the update.. perhaps do a trace using profiler to see what the server is up to.. perhaps it's busy rebuilding indexes or something similar at a guess. CPU load alone shows nothing

Comment: Yes, I did, nothing is running via the Profiler :(